# How to visualize cause and effect relationships with diagrams?

Tags: info-visualisation, mental-models

How can I model relationships where one or more causes produces an effect? I hope that such diagrams may make some of my ideas clearer to the user than just a block of text. **Are there some tools that I can use online to create cause and effect graphics?** Maybe there are some infographics I can take a look at that creatively combine causes to show an effect?

I'm looking for (X results in Y) or (X combined with Y results in Z) type of relationships, where X and Y are replaced with words, images or both.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be a stupid answer, but have you considered a "[cause and effect diagram](https://www.google.se/search?q=cause%20and%20effect%20diagram&aq=f&sugexp=chrome,mod=5&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=vruYUJbFEYr24QT_1YHQAQ&biw=1091&bih=896&sei=xbuYUKGwGrHY4QThl4HIDA)"?

[image: Cause and effect diagram]

Comment: Of course, the "fish"! Should've googled it.

Comment: @AlexStone LOL. I remebered it cause I work on fishbonesystems.com (which has nothing to do with the diagram above, but still it has a marker in my head at all times).